# Unable to upload firmware to the OpenCR for TurtleBot3

Tags: apt, package-management, permissions, dpkg

I'm following the setup from https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/opencr_setup/ to setup my TurtleBot3 and when I try:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:armhf
```

I get an error that says:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Are you *sure* you typed the `sudo`?

Comment: @David I am using Ubuntu 16.04